# How do photon gates act on ground and excited states?

Tags: photonics

https://strawberryfields.ai/photonics/conventions/gates.html#displacement

The above is the only profile of Photon Gate from Strawberry Fields.

I have the following doubts about Photon Gate:

1. Which of the photon gates are unitary and which are not?
2. can photon gates be written in the form of unitary matrices like superconducting gates (Hadamard gates)?
3. How do photon gates act on the ground state |0>?
4. why do photon gates choose to be represented by annihilation operators, isn't this more abstract and harder to compute?